# document.getElementById.checked returning undefined

Tags: jsp, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons using for each loop in jsp. Below is the code :

```
<c:forEach items="${PersonalInfo.employment.payPeriods}" var="option" varStatus="status">
                    <li class="radios incomePeriod" id="payPeriod${status.index}">
                        <html:radio property="employment.payPeriod" value="${option.value}" />${option.label}
                    </li>
                </c:forEach>
```

Basically, I need to get the value of the radio button. So I was trying to see which radio button is checked. I tried different options like :

`document.getElementById('payPeriod0').checked`  and

```
document.getElementById('payPeriod0').value
```

But all the options are giving me 'undefined'. Any idea where I am going wrong or what will be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use browser's Inspect or Developer Tools in final HTML and select one of the radio button element. Use that id in your code. Long way but it will give you a solution.

Comment: I did that too. When I did a browser debug , it was showing payPeriod0, payPeriod1 and payPeriod2 , and I used these ids, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this issue. Use the below jquery syntax to retrieve the data :

```
$("[name='employment.payPeriod']:checked").val()
```